# Google Sheets Formula to calculate actual total duration of tasks with different start/end dates, overlaps, and gaps

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I know I how to do this using a custom function/script but I am wondering if it can be done with a built-in formula.

I have a list of tasks with a start date and end date. I want to calculate the actual # of working days (`NETWORKDAYS`) spent on all the tasks.

- Task days may overlap so I can't just total the # of days spent on each task
- There may be gaps between tasks so I can't just find the difference between the first start and last end.

For example, let's use these:

```
| Task Name | Start Date | End Date   | NETWORKDAYS |
|:---------:|------------|------------|:-----------:|
|     A     | 2019-09-02 | 2019-09-04 |      3      |
|     B     | 2019-09-03 | 2019-09-09 |      5      |
|     C     | 2019-09-12 | 2019-09-13 |      2      |
|     D     | 2019-09-16 | 2019-09-17 |      2      |
|     E     | 2019-09-19 | 2019-09-23 |      3      |
```

Here it is visually:

[image]

Now:

- If you total the `NETWORKDAYS` you'll get 15
- If you calculate `NETWORKDAYS` between 2019-09-02 and 2019-09-23 you get 16

But the actual duration is 13:

- A and B overlap a bit
- There is a gap between B and C
- There is a gap between D and E

If I was to write a custom function I would basically take all the dates, sort them, find overlaps and remove them, and account for gaps.

But I am wondering if there is a way to calculate the actual duration using built-in formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, why not:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE("×"&
 SPLIT(REPT(INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTA(B1:B))&"×", 
 NETWORKDAYS(INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTA(B1:B)), INDIRECT("C1:C"&COUNTA(B1:B)))), "×")+
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(NETWORKDAYS(B1:B, C1:C))))-1)), "×"))), 
 "where Col1>4000", 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant. I'm trying to step through it to figure out how it works but not having much luck. At a high level, what exactly is it doing? Also, anyway to get it work if the first row has a header? I tried to replied A1/B1/C1 with A2/B2/C2 but it didn't work.

Comment: Okay, so converting each start date to a number, taking the start date number, create an array with each value 1 more than the previous with a length of the # of working days between start and end, remove duplicates, count... Is there a situation where adding the # of working days to the start date would not result in a duplicate?

Comment: nope. its more like: take the first column of start dates and duplicate each date by networkday. then split it into columns and add 0 to 1st column, add 1 to 2nd, 2 to 3rd etc, etc. then join everything into one single cell and split it into one single column. create unique list and remove low values that are not dates. and then just count output cells

Comment: fix for 2nd row: `=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE("×"&
 SPLIT(REPT(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1)&"×", 
 NETWORKDAYS(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1), INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(B2:B)+1))), "×")+
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(NETWORKDAYS(B2:B, C2:C))))-1)), "×"))), 
 "where Col1>4000", 0))))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb6Tf.png

Comment: Thank you. This works great. I made some minor changes to accommodate if a task doesn't have an end date. Would you mind if I edited your answer to reformat the function so it is easier to read and to add comments that explain what it does.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan be my guest