# Forecasting hotel room availability

Tags: google-sheets, charts, google-sheets-formula

I have a client that runs a hotel chain and I'm trying to understand and visualize the room availability across their hotels to enable me to run specific promotional campaigns for dates that have low bookings.

Ideally, I'd like to make a stacked bar chart which shows the number of rooms booked and the number of rooms available plotted against dates on the X-axis and room quantity on the Y-axis.

To help you understand the problem, here's a sample of the data I get access to: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q0wIDtzz15tGmrfbOn2eW38RNt7h8SfP-8wjKPWQtAU/edit?usp=sharing

My biggest challenge is data preparation for building out the chart. As you can see, I have two tables. One table tells me the total number of rooms available across the hotels *(this number stays constant)* and the second table is the weekly data dump I get from my client which tells me the arrival date & departure date for each booking made. It also tells me the revenue made on each booking.

So, based on this data, my question is:

How do I get the number of bookings & revenue on each date when I only have the start date & end date of the booking?

Comment: you could make a use of NETWORKDAY and then divide revenue per day per booking - https://stackoverflow.com/q/58140221/5632629

Answer (score 0):

Get a range of your dates, and then apply a countifs formula to it:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<="&D1,B:B,">"&D1)
```

Amend the A:A and B:B to the ranges containing your checking and checkout dates, and D1 to the cell your data is in. Then drag down the fill handle. It will count the amount of rooms booked out based on the day of check-in. Based on my experience with hotels, it will not count the checkout date as full since the room will be vacated before a certain time and can take a new booking for that date.

To get the revenue for each can be done with a similar sumifs function:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"<="&D1,B:B,">"&D1)
```

Where C:C is the range containing your daily revenue. This will do the same as above formula, but instead of counting it will sum the revenue for these dates.