# Expand/explode a Google Sheets table with ticket open and close stats to show all tickets open each month

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

My working example/sample Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AvAb_qnrrexYl5W5wAW6aA6P552T-prBxoONOis-XZM/edit?usp=sharing

I have a source table with information about tickets. For the sake of this question, there are only three columns that matter:

- Ticket ID
- Ticket Open Date
- Ticket Close Date -- if it is closed

From this information, I need to generate metrics/reports that show, for a specific month:

1. The tickets that were opened that month
2. The tickets that were closed that month
3. The tickets that were open (opened prior and not closed)

And, I need the raw data, not just the monthly summary. Meaning, I should be able to select a month and show all Ticket IDs that match the above three criteria.

Getting the first two is easy enough using this function (columns E-G in my sample sheet):

```
{
    QUERY(A2:C, "SELECT B, 'Opened', A WHERE A IS NOT NULL LABEL 'Opened' '' FORMAT B 'YYYY-MM'");
    QUERY(A2:C, "SELECT C, 'Closed', A WHERE C IS NOT NULL LABEL 'Closed' '' FORMAT C 'YYYY-MM'")
}
```

I am stuck at the 3rd one. I am trying to figure out how to break out every month a ticket is open. For every month a ticket is open there should be one row where:

- First column is the month
- Second column is "Open"
- Third column is the **Ticket ID**

For example:

- **ID0010**

  - opened in **2018-11**
  - closed in **2019-01**
  - open in:

    - **2018-12**
- **ID0019**

  - opened in **2018-08**
  - closed in **2019-03**
  - open in:

    - **2018-09**
    - **2018-10**
    - **2018-11**
    - **2018-12**
    - **2019-01**
    - **2019-02**

Would become:

```
| Month   | Status | Ticket ID |
|---------|--------|-----------|
| 2018-11 | Opened | ID0010    |
| 2018-12 | Open   | ID0010    |
| 2019-01 | Closed | ID0010    |
| 2018-08 | Opened | ID0019    |
| 2018-09 | Open   | ID0019    |
| 2018-10 | Open   | ID0019    |
| 2018-11 | Open   | ID0019    |
| 2018-12 | Open   | ID0019    |
| 2019-01 | Open   | ID0019    |
| 2019-02 | Open   | ID0019    |
| 2019-03 | Closed | ID0019    |
```

Note: The month a ticket was opened and closed would not also show an "Open" for the ticket. In other words, a ticket should only have "Open" on the months:

- After and not including opened
- Before and not including closed

And, if a ticket is not yet closed then it would one row for each month until today.

I thought I could use the concept in the accepted solution to [Google Sheets Formula to calculate actual total duration of tasks with different start/end dates, overlaps, and gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58140221/google-sheets-formula-to-calculate-actual-total-duration-of-tasks-with-different) but because of the size of data I am getting an error. The formula is in I2 of my sample sheet.

> Text result of CONCATENATE is longer than the limit of 50000 characters.

So I'm wondering if there is another way I could get the data I need. I know how to do this with a custom function but I am hoping to avoid a custom function if possible.

## update with solution

I was able to take key parts of [player0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0)'s answer and use it in my original solution. The short of it is, instead of using `CONCATENATE` to combine the columns/rows, use `QUERY` with `999^99` as the header count (3rd parameter) because `QUERY` will combine all the rows then (with a space separator).

The final formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    QUERY(
        SPLIT(
            TRANSPOSE(
                SPLIT(
                    QUERY(
                        TRANSPOSE(
                            TRIM(
                                QUERY(
                                    IF(
                                        A2:A <> "",
                                        A2:A & "," & EDATE(
                                            IFERROR(
                                                SPLIT(
                                                    REPT(
                                                        EOMONTH(B2:B, -1) + 1 & ",",
                                                        DATEDIF(
                                                            EOMONTH(B2:B, 0) + 1,
                                                            EOMONTH(
                                                                IF(
                                                                    C2:C <> "",
                                                                    C2:C,
                                                                    EDATE(TODAY(), 1)
                                                                ),
                                                                0
                                                            ),
                                                            "M"
                                                        )
                                                    ),
                                                    ","
                                                ),
                                                0
                                            ),
                                            TRANSPOSE(
                                                ROW(
                                                    INDIRECT(
                                                        "A1:A" & MAX(
                                                            IF(
                                                                B2:B <> "",
                                                                IFERROR(
                                                                    DATEDIF(
                                                                        EOMONTH(B2:B, 0) + 1,
                                                                        EOMONTH(
                                                                            IF(
                                                                                C2:C <> "",
                                                                                C2:C,
                                                                                EDATE(TODAY(), 1)
                                                                            ),
                                                                            0
                                                                        ),
                                                                        "M"
                                                                    ),
                                                                    0
                                                                ),
                                                            )
                                                        )
                                                    )
                                                )
                                            )
                                        ) & ";",
                                    ),
                                    ,
                                    999^99
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        ,
                        999^99
                    ) & " ",
                    "; "
                )
            ),
            ","
        ),
        "SELECT Col2, 'Open', Col1 WHERE Col2 > 4000 LABEL 'Open' '' FORMAT Col2 'YYYY-MM'",
        0
    )
)
```

## update to use SEQUENCE

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    QUERY(
        SPLIT(
            TRANSPOSE(
                SPLIT(
                    QUERY(
                        TRANSPOSE(
                            TRIM(
                                QUERY(
                                    IF(
                                        A2:A <> "",
                                        A2:A & "," & EDATE(
                                            IFERROR(
                                                SPLIT(
                                                    REPT(
                                                        EOMONTH(B2:B, -1) + 1 & ",",
                                                        DATEDIF(
                                                            EOMONTH(B2:B, 0) + 1,
                                                            EOMONTH(
                                                                IF(
                                                                    C2:C <> "",
                                                                    C2:C,
                                                                    EDATE(TODAY(), 1)
                                                                ),
                                                                0
                                                            ),
                                                            "M"
                                                        )
                                                    ),
                                                    ","
                                                ),
                                                0
                                            ),
                                            SEQUENCE(
                                                1,
                                                MAX(
                                                    IF(
                                                        B2:B <> "",
                                                        IFERROR(
                                                            DATEDIF(
                                                                EOMONTH(B2:B, 0) + 1,
                                                                EOMONTH(
                                                                    IF(
                                                                        C2:C <> "",
                                                                        C2:C,
                                                                        EDATE(TODAY(), 1)
                                                                    ),
                                                                    0
                                                                ),
                                                                "M"
                                                            ),
                                                            0
                                                        ),
                                                    )
                                                )
                                            )
                                        ) & ";",
                                    ),
                                    ,
                                    999^99
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        ,
                        999^99
                    ) & " ",
                    "; "
                )
            ),
            ","
        ),
        "SELECT Col2, 'Open', Col1 WHERE Col2 > 4000 LABEL 'Open' '' FORMAT Col2 'YYYY-MM'",
        0
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same logic:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 "♦"&FILTER(A2:A, B2:B<>"", C2:C<>"")&"♠"&SPLIT(REPT(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>"", C2:C<>"")+1&"♣",
 NETWORKDAYS(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>"", C2:C<>"")+1, FILTER(C2:C, B2:B<>"", C2:C<>""))), "♣")+
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(
 NETWORKDAYS(FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>"", C2:C<>"")+1, FILTER(C2:C, B2:B<>"", C2:C<>"")))))-1)&"♠")
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♠"),
 "select Col2,'Open',Col1 where Col2>4000 label 'Open''' format Col2 'YYYY-MM'", 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE("♦"&
 FILTER(A2:A, B2:B<>"", C2:C<>"", MONTH(B2:B)<>MONTH(C2:C), YEAR(B2:B)<>YEAR(C2:C))&"♠"&EOMONTH(SPLIT(REPT(
 FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>"", C2:C<>"", MONTH(B2:B)<>MONTH(C2:C), YEAR(B2:B)<>YEAR(C2:C))+1&"♣", DATEDIF(
 FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>"", C2:C<>"", MONTH(B2:B)<>MONTH(C2:C), YEAR(B2:B)<>YEAR(C2:C))+1, 
 FILTER(C2:C, B2:B<>"", C2:C<>"", MONTH(B2:B)<>MONTH(C2:C), YEAR(B2:B)<>YEAR(C2:C)), "M")-1), "♣"),
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(NETWORKDAYS(
 FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>"", C2:C<>"", MONTH(B2:B)<>MONTH(C2:C), YEAR(B2:B)<>YEAR(C2:C))+1, 
 FILTER(C2:C, B2:B<>"", C2:C<>"", MONTH(B2:B)<>MONTH(C2:C), YEAR(B2:B)<>YEAR(C2:C))))))))&"♠")
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♠"), 
 "select Col2,'Open',Col1 where Col2>4000 label 'Open''' format Col2 'YYYY-MM'", 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This doesn't show different months. For example, `ID0003` would not be in the list since it was opened and closed in the same month. `ID0010` would have one row for `2018-12`.

Comment: Looks like you're using `NETWORKDAYS` but I need to know how many months between...

Comment: I see. So, at its crux, instead of using `CONCATENATE`,  you're adding a field separator and using the `QUERY` heading joining aspect to concatenate. This is great. I forgot to mention it needs to factor in open tickets by using today's date but I think I can take what you provided and make it work. Let me see. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to use your data of combining columns with `QUERY` and add it to my function to get the desired end-result. I will update my question with the final answer that worked. Thank you!

Comment: I just realize I can also use the `SEQUENCE` function to generate the range of numbers 1 to x. doh!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I've updated my solution to use a sort of retabulation method that I like to use to turn 2D arrays into 2 column datasets.  This formula below is in C1 on this [sample sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p7k6FmmRN-rE1SZvQDLFOfcAFVcTLUaWFzWrIDe8oao/edit?usp=sharing)
You'll see a similar formula in F1 that skips the explosion and just does a ticket count by month if that's the goal of the graph.  Also there is a small formula in A1 that just calculates the max length of an open ticket in months.  This is used several times in the formula so, it's helpful, visually, to have a helper cell for it.  It can easily just be substituted into the large formulas in place of the A1 reference if you wanted to avoid having any helper cells.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A2:A)*A1,1,0)/A1+2,{ROW(Sheet1!A2:A),Sheet1!A2:A,IF(EDATE(EOMONTH(Sheet1!B2:B,-1)+1,SEQUENCE(1,A1,0))>EOMONTH(IFERROR(1/(1/Sheet1!C2:C),TODAY()),-1)+1,,EDATE(EOMONTH(Sheet1!B2:B,-1)+1,SEQUENCE(1,A1,0)))},MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A2:A)*A1,1,0),A1)*{0,1}+{2,3}),"where Col2 is not null label Col1'Ticket',Col2'Month'"))
```

Comment: I actually need the raw data exploded out so I can put it in a chart to show stats by month.

Comment: Ah, I understand. And I actually have a good, somewhat tidy method for that. Off to sleep now, but can get it posted in the morning.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan I updated my solution.  I realize you've already got what you're looking for, but you might find this method useful in the future.