# How to count networkdays in a subset of a date range with restrictions?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Demo workbook is here, now with formulas: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uj5P17iIesV6tEIwt00jUqJQdipxubk18CfV0uZshgU/edit?usp=sharing

This question is very similar to, but different from: [Expand/explode a Google Sheets table with ticket open and close stats to show all tickets open each month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60014382/expand-explode-a-google-sheets-table-with-ticket-open-and-close-stats-to-show-al/60018014#60018014) .

I have a list of job openings (Inputs tab) that I need to track for monthly metrics. My metrics need to count the number of job openings that were open for <=10 business days and those that are open for >10 business days in each month, ignoring holidays.

Each monthly total needs to count the net work days for said month and for any prior month. However it can't count any days after the end of said month. Any opening that hasn't closed needs to be counted from opening day to today().

For example, a job opens 12/31/2020 and closes 1/14/2021. Even though that job is open only 10 work days in January, it's counted as >10 because of the 1 extra work day from prior months.

A job that opens 1/29/2021 and closes 3/1/2021 would count as <=10 days for January because there's only 1 work day; >10 for February because there are 21 total work days; and >10 for March because there are 22 work days.

On the Monthly Metrics tab in the demo workbook, I need a formula to make B8:D9 match the answers in B2:D3 using the data from the Inputs tab.

The formula I have in B8 for counting jobs in December open <=10 days is:

=if(EOMonth(B$7,0)<Today(),(countA(filter(Inputs!$A$2:$A,Inputs!$B$2:$B="open", Inputs!$C$2:$C<=EOMonth(B$7,0), networkdays(Inputs!$C$2:$C,EOMonth(B$7,0))<=10))), (countA(filter(Inputs!$A$2:$A,Inputs!$B$2:$B="open", Inputs!$C$2:$C<=EOMonth(B$7,0), networkdays(Inputs!$C$2:$C,today())<=10))))

+if(EOMonth(B$7,0)<Today(),(countA(filter(Inputs!$A$2:$A,Inputs!$B$2:$B="closed", Inputs!$D$2:$D<=EOMonth(B$7,0), Inputs!$D$2:$D>=B$7, networkdays(Inputs!$C$2:$C,EOMonth(B$7,0))<=10))),(countA(filter(Inputs!$A$2:$A,Inputs!$B$2:$B="closed", Inputs!$D$2:$D<=EOMonth(B$7,0), Inputs!$D$2:$D>=B$7, networkdays(Inputs!$C$2:$C,Inputs!$D$2:$D)<=10))))

The formula I have in B9 for counting jobs in December open >10 days is:

=if(EOMonth(B$7,0)<Today(),(countA(filter(Inputs!$A$2:$A,Inputs!$B$2:$B="open", Inputs!$C$2:$C<=EOMonth(B$7,0), networkdays(Inputs!$C$2:$C,EOMonth(B$7,0))>10))), (countA(filter(Inputs!$A$2:$A,Inputs!$B$2:$B="open", Inputs!$C$2:$C<=EOMonth(B$7,0), networkdays(Inputs!$C$2:$C,today())>10))))

+if(EOMonth(B$7,0)<Today(),(countA(filter(Inputs!$A$2:$A,Inputs!$B$2:$B="closed", Inputs!$D$2:$D<=EOMonth(B$7,0), Inputs!$D$2:$D>=B$7, networkdays(Inputs!$C$2:$C,EOMonth(B$7,0))>10))),(countA(filter(Inputs!$A$2:$A,Inputs!$B$2:$B="closed", Inputs!$D$2:$D<=EOMonth(B$7,0), Inputs!$D$2:$D>=B$7, networkdays(Inputs!$C$2:$C,Inputs!$D$2:$D)>10))))

As you can see, The counts are way off, and I can't keep the logic straight in my head, or on paper, well enough to figure it out.

Comment: While this issue is solvable, as most are, my opinion is that it goes beyond what a free volunteer-run forum is designed to offer. Forums such as these are here to offer a little knowledge or a "nudge in the right direction" to people who've already researched the issue and nearly solved their own issues via formula or script, but who may have gotten stuck in some small point. The forums aren't designed to be places where people can get full customized, time-intensive solutions at no cost.

Comment: In keeping with sharing of knowledge, however, I will say that in looking at your numbers in the "Monthly Metrics" sheet, they appear to me to have been entered opposite of what they should be. You may want to double check that and make corrections as necessary, as incorrect data will only make the task more difficult if, in fact, a volunteer contributor here chooses to take this on despite the time investment.

Comment: @ErikTyler, thank you for the catch. I've corrected the info on that tab. I can update the demo with a few of the different solutions I've tried in the past. I've been so frustrated with each of them though, I initially didn't see value in sharing. I'm happy to respect the intent and purpose of the form though.

Comment: can you explain why cell H7 on "inputs" tab says 1.

It seems that there are no workdays at all and it should be 0.  What don't I understand?

Comment: @MattKing - user error. I forgot to verify the sample dates when I input them. I've corrected the dates in question to actual workdays, and they should sum to 2

Comment: I think the question is clear enough to come up with an idea, but my guess is that it won't work when trying to apply it to 'the real sheet'.  It is often that application of a complex idea to the real sheet that i think is the real work and perhaps what Erik was alluding you might want to pay for if you can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checksum - networkdays per period:

```
={"Checksum"; INDEX(NETWORKDAYS(C2:C11, IF(D2:D11="", TODAY(), D2:D11)))}
```

[image]

networkdays per each month:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A1:A11)&"", QUERY({TEXT(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="",TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)>=
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="", TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)+1), ), ROW(C2:C11)&"×"&C2:C11+SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="", TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)+1), ), NA())), 
 "where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, ROW(C2:C11)&"×"&C2:C11, ".*"&VALUE(UNIQUE(EOMONTH(SEQUENCE(TODAY()-MIN(C2:C11), 1, MIN(C2:C11)), -1)+1)))&"'"), "×"), {"#", "yyy-mm"}), NETWORKDAYS(
 INDEX(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="",TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)>=
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="", TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)+1), ), ROW(C2:C11)&"×"&C2:C11+SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="", TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)+1), ), NA())), 
 "where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, ROW(C2:C11)&"×"&C2:C11, ".*"&VALUE(UNIQUE(EOMONTH(SEQUENCE(TODAY()-MIN(C2:C11), 1, MIN(C2:C11)), -1)+1)))&"'"), "×"),,2), 
 INDEX(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="",TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)>=
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="", TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)+1), ), ROW(C2:C11)&"×"&C2:C11+SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="", TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)+1), ), NA())), 
 "where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, ROW(D2:D11)&"×"&IF(D2:D11="", TODAY(), D2:D11), ".*"&VALUE(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(EOMONTH(SEQUENCE(TODAY()-MIN(C2:C11), 1, MIN(C2:C11)), )))))&"'"), "×"),,2))}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3) group by Col1 pivot Col2 label Col1'1'"), SEQUENCE(1, COUNTUNIQUE(EOMONTH(SEQUENCE(TODAY()-MIN(C2:C11), 1, MIN(C2:C11)), )))+1, 0)))
```

[image]

and your monthly metrics would be:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(TEXT(TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(EOMONTH(SEQUENCE(TODAY()-MIN(C2:C11), 1, MIN(C2:C11)), ))), "yyymm\¤mmm-yyy")&"×"&
 REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(QUERY({TEXT(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="",TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)>=
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="", TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)+1), ), ROW(C2:C11)&"×"&C2:C11+SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="", TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)+1), ), NA())), 
 "where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, ROW(C2:C11)&"×"&C2:C11, ".*"&VALUE(UNIQUE(EOMONTH(SEQUENCE(TODAY()-MIN(C2:C11), 1, MIN(C2:C11)), -1)+1)))&"'"), "×"), {"#", "yyy-mm"}), NETWORKDAYS(
 INDEX(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="",TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)>=
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="", TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)+1), ), ROW(C2:C11)&"×"&C2:C11+SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="", TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)+1), ), NA())), 
 "where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, ROW(C2:C11)&"×"&C2:C11, ".*"&VALUE(UNIQUE(EOMONTH(SEQUENCE(TODAY()-MIN(C2:C11), 1, MIN(C2:C11)), -1)+1)))&"'"), "×"),,2), 
 INDEX(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="",TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)>=
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="", TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)+1), ), ROW(C2:C11)&"×"&C2:C11+SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(IF(D2:D11="", TODAY(), D2:D11), C2:C11)+1), ), NA())), 
 "where Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, ROW(D2:D11)&"×"&IF(D2:D11="", TODAY(), D2:D11), ".*"&VALUE(UNIQUE(EOMONTH(SEQUENCE(TODAY()-MIN(C2:C11), 1, MIN(C2:C11)), ))))&"'"), "×"),,2))}, 
 "select sum(Col3) group by Col1 pivot Col2"), "offset 1", 0)&"", "(\b([0-9]|10)\b)", "$1×# Jobs open <= 10 business days")&"", "(.*\d$)", "$1×# Jobs open > 10 business days")), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null"), "select Col3,count(Col2) group by Col3 pivot Col1")&"", "(.*¤)", ))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, did not expect it to be that complex. Thanks!

Comment: My only issue with this solution is that I already have column L and row 1, and only need a formula to calculate the numeric values. Would that simplify things at all?